# Can NCalc be configured to evaluate a bool to 0 or 1?

Tags: ncalc

I just got caught by surprise because management thinks it's a good idea to use Boolean expressions in calculations such as

```
x = (y < 4) * 1 + (z < 8) * 4 ...
```

I use NCalc for formula evaluation, unfortunately NCalc complains because I'm trying to multiply an integer and a bool.

Is there a way to expand NCalc so false is converted to 0 and true is converted to 1 or will I have to dig deep and make some modifications to the NCalc codebase?

Comment: Seems like a rather low-level thing for management to be dictating IMO...

Comment: Product management. We ship software which, among other things, features assessments,  the configuration of which involves free-form calculations that can be imported from XML. Product management is responsible for these configuration files.

Comment: OK, I suppose that might make some sense there. That said, I doubt you'll be able to do it without modifying the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up changing the source code. Just in case anybody should run into the same issue, there's a bunch of switch statements in Numbers.cs where you can change the behavior for every type of operator. In my particular case that was Multiply(object a, object b) where I changed the default behavior from throwing an exception to this:

```
case TypeCode.Int32:
   switch (typeCodeB)
   {
      case TypeCode.Boolean: return ((bool) b) ? (Int32)a : 0;
   }
...
```